# Does opening a fridge more often make it stop working faster?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, home-experiment

My fridge stopped working today, and it was open the whole previous night.

I was arguing that keeping the door open has nothing to do with the compressor to stop working. Because the compressor doesn't know that the door is open moreover it is a 15 year old fridge so there is no temperature sensor. So the compressor is running whether the door is open or closed.

Also the only thing is that since the temperature difference between inside and outside is lesser the efficiency of the fridge decreases.

However the other person keeps arguing that the fridge can sense the temperature and automatically turns off when it is cool enough only to turn on when it becomes hot inside. Who is right?

Comment: This is an engineering question, try the [engineering SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: -1. Not clear. What is the argument of the other person? Saying it is "otherwise" and then asking us to decide between the two arguments does not allow us to evaluate any merits of the other person'sexplanation.

Comment: There is a temperature sensor.  Fridges have had thermostats for nearly a hundred years.  If you leave the door open the thing will run flat out and yes, probably kill itself as a result.

Comment: "it is a 15 year old fridge so there is no temperature sensor"  How bad do you think technology was 15 years ago?

Answer (score 3):

The compressor is part of a larger system, a heat pump. A fridge has a heat pump because the isolation is not optimal - heat leaks in from the outside. This needs to be removed.

How much heat needs to be removed? Not all heat, certainly. A fridge is not a freezer, and event your ordinary household freezer doesn't try to turn air into liquid nitrogen. There's always a thermostat. Not just in a 15 year old fridge, even in 50 year old fridges. There might not be a digital display *showing* the temperature, though.

So, the thermostat shuts off the heat pump if the fridge is cold enough, and turns it back on when more heat has accumulated. With an open door, more heat gets in and the heat pump has to work much harder. Keeping it open for a night may well have kept the compressor running all night. And that's likely not what it was engineered for, not even when it was new.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually have in reality is a heater rather than a fridge. Law of thermodynamics state that heat cannot be transferred from a cold body to a hot body without doing work. In your case, if a fridge is kept in an isolated room with the door open, the net temperature of the room will only increase as electricity is converted into net heat by the refrigerator.